# Some customers get low ReCaptcha v3 scores

Tags: recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

I have successfully integrated appCheck on Firestore (in a Flutter/dart webapp) using reCaptcha v3 and, according to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin, there are about 5% suspicious requests.

My app is used in schools (by pupils) and some schools report, at startup, an AppCheck error. When the AppCheck error occurs, I added an extra call to reCaptchaV3 myself to analyze this in more detail and, as expected, I get a low recaptcha score (see example below)

{"success":true,"challenge_ts":"2023-11-13T14:05:40Z","hostname":"","score":0.1,"action":"submit"}

The problems seem to be school specific so I would like to understand what they can do to get a higher captcha score (and hence be able to use our app)

I understand that the captcha validation is a black box but can you give me some pointers/options that I can investigate?

Is it possible that they get a low captcha score because eg 30 pupils start our app at almost the same time?

One other option that I considered was an outdated browser version but that doesn't seem to be the case either

Other suggestions are appreciated!